# PHP GET URL ERROR

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, get

I have multiple checkboxes and onClick i am sending values to URL and GETTING values from URL in PHP so that i could select results from query.

If i select market US and International then URL IS ***"product.php?market=US"*** 
but when I select tiles and slabs then it displays ***"product.php?market=US-International&type=tiles&type=slabs"***
and after when i go back and select market again to international then it shows ***"product.php?market=US&type=tiles&type=slabs&market=International"***

How do i manage get values in the url like daraz.pk/women/clothing/kurtas-shalwar-kameez/ is doing on filter on the left.

Checkbox structer :

**Market :**

US
International

**Type :**

Tiles
Slabs

**Category :**

Oynyx
ETC

```
CODE :

<div class="widgetTitle">
                        <h3 class="garis">Market</h3>
                        <div class="productsline"></div>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="categories">



 <input  name="check_list[]" onclick="window.location.href = '?market=Pakistan'"  type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="regular-checkbox" /><label for="checkbox-1"></label>




 <input  name="check_list[]" onclick="window.location.href = '?International&'" type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" class="regular-checkbox" /><label for="checkbox-2"></label>

                    International





                    </nav>
                </div>

    <div class="widgetTitle">
                        <h3 class="garis">Type</h3>
                            <div class="productsline"></div>
                    </div>

                    <nav class="categories">



<input  name="check_list[]" onclick="window.location.href = '&type=blocks'"  type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" class="regular-checkbox" /><label for="checkbox-3"></label>
Blocks




 <input  name="check_list[]" onclick="window.location.href = '<?=$path;?>&type=slabs'"  type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" class="regular-checkbox" /><label for="checkbox-4"></label>

                    Slabs


 <input  name="check_list[]" onclick="window.location.href = '&type=tiles'"  type="checkbox" id="checkbox-5" class="regular-checkbox" /><label for="checkbox-5"></label>

                    Tiles


 <input  name="check_list[]" onclick="window.location.href = '&type=mosaics'"  type="checkbox" id="checkbox-6" class="regular-checkbox" /><label for="checkbox-6"></label>

                    Mosaics




                    </nav>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you share your code here?

Comment: Put the parameters and values into an array, using the parameter name as key. And then simply use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to generate the query string out of that.

Comment: ´"product.php?market=US&type=tiles&type=slabs&market=International"´You have multiple market keys in the same string which is wrong.

Comment: @NiclasLarsson yes thats what i want to modify.

Comment: @CBroe could you please write a sample code ? I am stuck with it

Comment: You have not even shown us yet how “selecting” a filter option in your page works.

Comment: @CBroe just pasted the code. pls check

Comment: Ah, so you are doing this client-side. Would be easier if you used a real form for this – then parameters with the same name would overwrite former ones automatically. If that’s not an option, than you will have to get the parameters from the URL in JS beforehand, replace the one parameter that should be changed (if already existent) , and build the new query string.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building the url with php or javascript?

With php:

```
$_GET['market'] = 'your new market';

echo http_build_query( $_GET );
```

After your edit:

```
onClick="?<?php echo http_build_query( array('market' => 'Pakistan') + $_GET ); ?>"
```

Comment: I don't need url rewrite I need to parse the values